# Formatting a calendar date

Tags: android, date, formatting, calendar

I just want the date to show up like so:

`Saturday, May 26, 2012 at 10:42 PM`

Here's my code so far:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String theDate = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

lastclick.setText(getString(R.string.lastclick) + " " + theDate);
```

This shows the numbers of the month, day, and year, but there's got to be a better way of doing this? Isn't there some simple way of doing this like using PHP's `date()` function?

Comment: yes. dont see why this is so difficult.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the below to format the date as required. Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 lastclick.setText(getString(R.string.lastclick) + " " + String.format("%1$tA %1$tb %1$td %1$tY at %1$tI:%1$tM %1$Tp", calendar));
```

Where %1$tA for staurday,
%1$tb for May,

and so on...

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this one, but I don't seem able to remove my upvote without downvoting, which isn't necessary. This one works, but the one below is more straightforward and much easier to read.

Comment: String.format("%1\$tA %1\$tb %1\$td %1\$tY at %1\$tI:%1\$tM %1\$Tp", calendar)

Answer (score 126):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Running the above code outputs the current time (e.g., `Saturday, May 26, 2012 at 11:03 PM`).

See the [Android documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information.

The format specification of `SimpleDateFormat` is similar to that of PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
echo date("l, M j, Y \a\\t g:i A");
```

You're right. Compared to the Java code, the PHP code is much more succinct.

Comment: Your code generates the specific format the asker wanted, but what if I want the format to be set according to the user's system settings? On Windows, C# code DateTime.ToLongDateString() generates that. What if I want to achieve the same thing on Android?

Comment: See my answer for a solution that includes locale.

Answer (score 17):

This is actually a fairly subtle problem to get right, and I've not seen another answer here on SO that addresses both:

- The `Calendar`'s time zone (which means that it might be showing a different date than local)
- The device's `Locale` (which affects the "right" way to format dates)

The previous answers to this question ignore locale, and other answers that involve conversion to a `Date` ignore the time zone. So here's a more complete, general solution:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // the value to be formatted
java.text.DateFormat formatter = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(
        java.text.DateFormat.LONG); // one of SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG, FULL, or DEFAULT
formatter.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
String formatted = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Note that you need to use `java.text.DateFormat` here, not Android's own (confusingly-named) `android.text.format.DateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler answer:

```
SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(cal.getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works perfectly:

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

val pattern = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a"
val primaryLocale = getLocales(resources.configuration).get(0)
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern, primaryLocale)

val formatedDate: String = dateFormat.format(cal.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution which is a mix of the other answers and also includes time

You can customize the `DateFormat.SHORT` parts to other constants to show more/different details

Short leads to this on my device: `17/07/2021 04:11`

You can simply pass `Calendar.getInstance()` to get the current time

```
fun formatDateTime(calendar: Calendar):String{
    val formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,DateFormat.SHORT)
    formatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
    return formatter.format(calendar.time)
}
```