# android: how to display the month and years in words from the Calender Date in android?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

i am getting a date from server in this format ----->>>>> 2013-1-18

i need to show the date in the following format------->>>> Thursday,January 18

How to do it?????

Comment: there is an example on how to do that on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771279/formatting-a-calendar-date). Good luck :)

Comment: try something before asking. try searching, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can format it easily using [**java.text.SimpleDateFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
            SimpleDateFormat sString s= "2013-1-18";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM, dd ");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse(s)));df
```

Output:

```
Friday,January, 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. Basically you can following: parse string to date using `SimpleDateFormat`, convert date to desired format using again `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

try use SimpleDateFormat class

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: even though the answer is correct, i am very tempted to downvote, as this kind of answer encourages this kind of questions.